# How to cluster MS Access 2010 objects by type in menu?

Tags: ms-access

I recall that previous versions of Access had separate menus for each object type, e.g. all tables were listed in one menu, views (queries) in another etc.

For some reason, the latest Access is organizing them in a hierarchical fashion, listing tables and under each table views that are based off of that table:

```
Table1
--View1 (off of Table1)
--View2 (off of Table1)
Table2
--View3 (off of Table2)
--View4 (off of Table2)
etc.
```

I don't like to look at my DB objects like that, I want them clustered by type, like every other DB client in the world organizes the view of objects.

Any idea if I can configure Access to list objects clustered by type.  E.g.

```
Tables
-----------
Table1
Table2
Tabls3

Views
------------
View1
View2
etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the order from the dropdown list. The selection illustrated is the plain list you require. I suspect your current selection is Tables and Related Views.

[image: access 2010 object order]

Comment: Also, here are some tips on using the nav pane from a developer point of view. The tips in this article should help you regain if not exceed your productivity when working with the new ribbon UI. http://www.kallal.ca/Articles/navpne/NavTips.html